# Converting characters inside file to upper case matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to convert all the characters inside a file to uppercase in matlab. I have searched in Matlab's documentation but I didn't find anything that helped. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Read file, use [upper](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/upper.html), write file...

Comment: I can't imagine you tried very hard. `lookfor uppercase` only returns one result: `upper`. This is also the first hit for a Google search for: matlab uppercase. Good questions on StackOverflow should show a little bit of research and an attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

That's too simple:

```
x=upper(fileread('c:\filename.txt'));
```

Comment: You forgot to store the file again :p

Comment: _"convert all the characters **inside** a file"_ sounds to me like that, but I admit that the problem description is not 100% clear...